# How to Develop WPF Multi-Touch Application without a Touch Screen?

Tags: wpf

I'm tasked with creating a multi-touch application but I don't have a multitouch screen or device and ours don't arrive for a month (Grr!)

Is there some kind of emulation or cheap USB device that we can get that will work with WPF in .NET 4 for the interim?

Answer (score 4):

if your are using windows 8 just you need to use Microsoft Windows Simulator Touch Emulation , 
it simulate all  touch event within mouse , just run in  `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Simulator\11.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe` and for X86 OS -> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\12.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe`

**Edit :**
for Visual Stuido 2017 Check This Address : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Simulator\15.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe`

Comment: As far as I understand, the tool is for developing Metro style apps for Windows 8. It requires, WinRT and other features that are unique to Windows 8. Therefore it's not for ordinary WPF apps.

Comment: yes your right , it is just tools for debug any touch application in windows 8 not only wpf , it will install with VS 2012

Comment: I'm using 64-bit Windows and VS 2013, so on my machine it's located in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\12.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe`

Comment: @pogosama thanks I got your comment help to find the same

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 on x64: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Simulator\15.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe`

Answer (score 2):

Its probably a bit late now but for anyone else use [Multitouch Vista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) to enable emulating a Windows 7 touch device and in turn it will work with WPF4 (Using multiple USB mice is the easiest and reliable way). Make sure to follow the youtube video on the main page to how to set up etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are some small usb touch devices (like the Mimo iMo) but I'm not aware of any that have multitouch support beyond trackpad type gestures. As far as software emulation, the [Surface SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3DB8987B-47C8-46CA-AAFB-9C3B36F43BCC&displayLang=en) includes a very good simulator but the touch APIs for Surface, while in WPF, are a bit different from .NET 4. It may allow you to prove out and test your multitouch scenarios and then transplant that code into your full WPF application. Get the [Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=801907a7-b2dd-4e63-9ff3-8a2e63932a74) too to give you a head start.